# Two instances of Conky keeps flickering

Tags: ssh, xfce, conky, raspberrypi, multiple-instances

I would like to have two instances of conky running om my screen (possibly three later on) as I would like to show statistics from my two Raspberry Pi's. I'm running Xubuntu/XFCE4 by the way :)

I already have the two config files ready and the *local* script executes like this

```
sh -c "sleep 10; conky;"
```

And the *remote* script executes like this

```
ssh -X pi@192.168.1.190 sh -c "sleep 10; conky;"
```

Both scripts seem to be working individually - bot not at the same time. When they both run the instances flickers and switch between being visible.

Both scripts are almost identical - and really not very fancy - just useful.

```
# GENERAL CONFIGURATIONS
out_to_x yes 

# Update interval in seconds
update_interval 5.0

# Text alignment, other possible values are commented
alignment bottom_left

# Aligning vertical
gap_y 15
gap_x 10      <-- This variable is set to 100 in the local script

# Use double buffering (reduces flicker)
double_buffer yes

TEXT
$nodename - $sysname $kernel on $machine
$stippled_hr
${color lightgrey}Uptime:$color $uptime ${color lightgrey}- Load:$color $loadavg
${color lightgrey}CPU Usage:${color #cc2222} $cpu% ${cpubar}
${color lightgrey}RAM Usage:$color $mem/$memmax - $memperc% ${membar}
$color$stippled_hr
${color lightgrey}File systems:
ROOT $color${fs_used /}/${fs_size /} ${fs_bar /}
SLAVE $color${fs_used /media/slave}/${fs_size /media/slave} ${fs_bar /media/slave}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why what you're doing would cause flickering, but try adding these to your `.conkyrc`:

```
text_buffer_size 556
own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_argb_visual yes
```

Not at all sure that this will help but it might.

Comment: **own_window_argb_visual yes** and **text_buffer_size 556** did the trick. Thanks :)